C# convert int to 16 bit big endian byte order
I'm trying to convert PHP pack() function to C#
<?php
// taken from FCGI Protocol
function packPayload()
{
    return pack("nCa5", 1, 0, "");
}

echo json_encode(packPayload());

# \u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000
                          

from the PHP doc:
n   unsigned short (always 16 bit, big endian byte order)
C   unsigned char
a   NUL-padded string

The C# Code
for  n, it should return \u0001 instead \u0000
var n = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)1)); // n
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(n); // \u0000

for C it error
var C = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes((byte)0));
error: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:....

for a5 i think it safe to just use \u0000 then prepend previous value 5 times
about fcgi protocol, it socket connection used by PHP-FPM and others fastcgi app, it replace old CGI connection.
reference:
https://www.mit.edu/~yandros/doc/specs/fcgi-spec.html
https://github.com/FastCGI-Archives/fcgi2/blob/master/cgi-fcgi/cgi-fcgi.c


Is this what you need?
Parameter / encoding validation is up to you as I do not know your requirements or the mentioned FCGI protocol in detail.
using System.Buffers.Binary;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

static string EscapeString(ReadOnlySpan<byte> data)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new(data.Length * 6);
    foreach (byte b in data)
        sb.Append($@"\u{b:x4}");
    return sb.ToString();
}

static string Pack(ushort n, byte c, string a)
{
    Span<byte> data = stackalloc byte[2 + 1 + 5];

    BinaryPrimitives.WriteUInt16BigEndian(data, n);
    data[2] = c;
    Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(a, data[3..]);

    return EscapeString(data);
}

Console.WriteLine(Pack(1, 0, ""));
// "\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"


please have a look the php output, it should return n 1 => \u0000 and C 0 => \u0001

@uingtea This code yields the exact output you commented in your question. Are you sure you didn't mix up bytes here (what if n=2 and c=3)? Can you add test case inputs and expected outputs (also link the FCGI protocol in question if possible, at least if others have the time to read it)?

modified version seem to be work, thank you.
